react-spring basic transition with components - background appears, component doesn't "pre-render"
I'm trying to reproduce the "Basic Transition" example from the react-spring website with components imported from a file instead of animated.divs (https://codesandbox.io/s/cisbc).
However, after replacing the animated.divs with my imported components, the animation isn't quite working - you can briefly see the background appear between each animation.  What am I doing wrong?  Here's the codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/p/github/aaronzshey/reactspring-sandbox/main

Turns out, all I needed to do was add position: absolute to the imported animated element (the Page component in the code).  That was it!

Could you please be specific with answer. What was there and what has been changes. Something like before and after.
